# Cannot find error related to dynamic memory. (Most probably)

Tags: c++

I am relatively new to programming. I was given the task to create a game, which allows a user to create different soccer players, pair them up in teams and simulate matches between the teams based on the players' stats. For that purpose I decided to save the information about every single player in one .txt file and the information about every separate team on a separate .txt file.
I won't go into details about my Player class since it seems to be working fine. These are its members(in the header file):

```
class Player {
string m_name;
int m_age;
string m_team;
string m_position;
double m_speed;
```

And its main 2 funcitons. I've excluded setters and getters:

```
void save ();
static vector<Player*> load();
```

"Save" saves the info for a player to the .txt file, and "Load" creates a vector with pointers to every player of the .txt file

Now the class I'm having troubles with - Team.

```
class Team{
string m_name;
vector<Player*> m_players;
bool m_type;
double m_coach;
```

Function choose players - it allows the user to choose the players for his team from a list of all players in Players.txt

```
void Team :: choosePlayers (){
    vector<Player*> temp = Player::load();
    vector<Player*> choice;
    vector<int> numbers;
    vector<string> strings;
    string userChoice;
    for (int i=0; i < temp.size(); i++){
            cout<<i+1<<". "<<temp[i]->getName()<<" "<<temp[i]->getAge()<<" "<<temp[i]->getPosition()<<" "<<temp[i]->getSpeed()<<endl;
        }
    cout<< "CHOOSE YOUR PLAYERS BY PRESSING THEIR CORRESPONDIG NUMBERS. SEPARATE DIFFERENT PLAYERS WITH SPACES."<<endl;
    getline (cin, userChoice);
    strings = splitString(userChoice);
    numbers = convertToInt(strings);
    for (int q=0; q < numbers.size(); q++){
            choice.push_back(temp[(numbers[q])-1]);
        }
    this->m_players = choice;
}
```

(splitToString and convertToInt are just functions I used to separate the user's input - e.g "1 5 7" into a vector with 3 integers {1,5,7})

```
void save (){
    char* dir = new char[199];
    char* cstrName = new char[m_name.length()];
    strcpy(dir, "D:/C++ projects/Project project project/Team data/ "); //the directory of the save locations
    strcpy(cstrName, m_name.c_str());
    strcat (dir, cstrName);
    strcat (dir, ".txt");
    ofstream osF (dir);
    osF<<m_name<<endl;
    osF<<m_type<<endl;
    osF<<m_coach<<endl;
   for(int i=0; i < m_players.size(); i++){
        osF<<m_players[i]->getName()<<endl;
        osF<<m_players[i]->getAge()<<endl;
        osF<<m_players[i]->getTeam()<<endl;
        osF<<m_players[i]->getPosition()<<endl;
        osF<<m_players[i]->getSpeed()<<endl;
    }
    }
```

It saves the information about a team and its players into a separate .txt file with the same name as the team's name.

And finally its access modifiers

```
void Team :: setName(){
    string temp;
    getline(cin, temp);
    this->m_name = temp;
    }
void Team :: setType(){
    bool temp = 0;
    cin>>temp;
    this->m_type = temp;
    }
void Team :: setCoach(){
    double temp = 0;
    cin>>temp;
    this->m_coach = temp;
    }
```

Here's the problem. When I run functions choosePlayers, any of the access modifiers or save (of class Team) separately they all work as intended. However, when I try to run for example,

```
Team obj1;
obj1.setName();
obj1.choosePlayers();
obj1.save;
```

I sometimes get runtime error c0000005 (I've read it's realted to dynamic memory overwrite, or accessing not existing array index) or the function choosePlayers doesn't seem to execute properly: It shows a list of all available players, but it doesn't let the user input his choice. The program just returns 0 as if completed successfully.

I've been looking at my code for hours now and I cannot seem to find what goes wrong. I would be grateful if anyone takes a look and points me in the right direction

Comment: Consider to use a SQLite database.

Comment: @manni66 while sage advice for someone wanting a light database, it is not-helpful to the OPs problem (which is no-doubt ultimately rooted in invoking undefined behavior *somewhere*). Whether the OP stores their data in a text file, a sqlite database, or a clustered DB2 instance makes no difference to how the code manages the data once it is off the disk and in memory. The OP should run their code in a debugger, and ideally dispense with the manual memory management in favor of smart pointers, or better still, dispense with it entirely if possible.

Comment: Why do you store pointers?

Comment: @manni66 First, thank you for the reply. As I mentioned I'm a new programmer. (Wrote my first lines of code a month and a half ago). What exactly does running my code in a debugger mean? I use the IDE Code::Blocks. Is runninng my code though a debugger the same as pressing f9? 

what do smart pointers mean? Do they manage memory on their own?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I was taught that pointers require next to no memory (1 byte ?). Figured out it would be way more efficient to use pointers instead of copying the whole objects when copying vectors with players (I do it on several occasions)

Comment: @DanailNedkov: You were taught wrong, on both counts. You've made your program far more complicated (which directly led to this bug, in all probability) for effectively no gain.

Comment: But aren't pointers AT LEAST less memory consuming?

Comment: How does the load function create new players? On the stack or the heap? Pointers are not 1 byte (4 or 8 typically). If you are worried about copying large objects you should use const references.